# Create select in JQuery with Ajax request to get current subscription

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

If a user has a subscription and they want to upgrade/downgrade I need a select list to show the other options that they don't have in JQuery.

I have the subscription they have in my DB so I am assuming I need to make an ajax request to get the subscription they have I just don't know how to create a select while not showing what they already have.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more than that. Database structure perhaps? Maybe a code snippet of what you've already written in JS/PHP.

Comment: The jQuery docs are your friend.  Look up `$.ajax`

Comment: @Coulto `$.post` is also a possibility

Comment: @SuperDJ or even `$.get` depending on the circumstances xD

Comment: i have the users subscription returned from the DB which is select id of what choice they have. So the DB returns bronze and in the select list the id is bronze. I need to make an ajax request to get that result, then dynamically create a select to display that doesn't show that option

Comment: No i know to look up the docs i am just iffy with ajax, I was just looking for a better explanation to attack this.

Comment: You could make a call to a php file and there you can have sql = select * from your_table where id !=?; and you could pass the variable with the ajax call to that file and will return everything except that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

HTML

```
<div>Your current level : <span id="currentSubsLevel">Bronze</span></div>
<select id="subsList"></select>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentSubsLevel = $("#currentSubsLevel").text();
    $.post(
       "your url",
       {currentSubsLevel :currentSubsLevel },
       function(data){$("#subsList").html(data);}
    )
});
```

PHP/MySql

```
----your url page----
$csl = $_POST['currentSubsLevel'];
$res = mysql_query("SELECT subsLebels FROM SubscriptionTable WHERE subsLevels !='".$csl."'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['subsLebels']; ?>"><?php echo $row['subsLebels']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```